# Updating object property, initially set to an undefined array element

Tags: javascript

```
var A = [];

var obj = {
    x: A[1],
    y: 'hello'
};

A[1] = 1;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // {"y":"hello"}
```

By the time I'm using `obj` in `console.log()`, `A[1]` has already been defined.

How can I get the "latest" `obj`, with all its properties updated ? Such that we get `{"x":1,"y":"hello"}` when we do `console.log()` ?

Comment: An explanatory [article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) on the topic (see the #javascript-prototypal-inheritance section).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You are getting the latest object.* If you want the `x` property to update as its assigned value changes throughout the runtime of the code you need to use an object, since it will just store a reference to it and as the place in memory changes you will see those changes everywhere you assigned it. Arrays are considered objects so you could just assign `A` to `x`.

```
var A = [];

var obj = {
    x: A,
    y: 'hello'
};

A[1] = 1;

alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Another example using an object as value:

```
var A = [];
var B = {};
A[1] = B;

var obj = {
    x: A[1],
    y: 'hello'
};

B.z = 1;

alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: `{"x":[null,1],"y":"hello"}`?

Comment: Well thats simply because A[0] was never instantiated. But primitive values are not references. If you want to see that property update over time it needs to be assigned the reference of an object. I chose the array as that object so you will see all its values.

Comment: Is it possible to have reference to a `var` as the value of `obj.x`? So if that var changes `obj.x` will reflect that. I suppose not

Comment: Yes if the value of obj.x is an object itself. I'll update answer with an example. You could some kind of data-binding library too.

Answer (score 3):

`A[1] = 1;` is actually defined when `obj` was already constructed. So `obj.x` is always `undefined`.

```js
var A = [];
A[1] = 1;
var obj = {
  x: A[1],
  y: 'hello'
};
document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming you want the value of `obj.x` as a primitive :*

It's not possible to assign the reference of a `var` to `obj.x`.You can make `obj.x` as a function that'll get the latest value of that variable

```
 var variable= 2
 var obj = {
     x: function() {
         return variable;
     },
     y: 'hello'
  };

  variable = 5;

  console.log(obj.x()); //prints 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects are not reinitialised by reference.
You need to do obj.x = 1 to update the object.